Setting Cookies Domain with pinia persisit store on Nuxt 3
I'm setting up SSO login for two apps on the same sub-domain using Nuxt 3 with Pinia and persisting data in cookie storage. The issue is configuring the cookie's domain option so that it's accessible across both apps on different sub-domains.
import { defineStore } from "pinia";


export const useAuthStore = defineStore(
  "auth",
  () => {
  const loggedUser = ref("");
  const hasPin = ref(false);
  const language = ref(window?.navigator?.language);
  const isLoggedIn = computed(() => !!loggedUser.value);
  const refresh_token = computed(() => loggedUser?.value?.jwToken);
  const access_token = computed(() => loggedUser?.value?.jwToken);
  const roles = computed(() => loggedUser?.value?.roles);
  const userId = computed(() => loggedUser?.value?.id);
  const businessId = computed(() => loggedUser?.value?.businessId);
  const userInfo = computed(() => loggedUser?.value);

function setLoggedUser(data) {
  loggedUser.value = data;
  cookie.value = data
}

function setHasPin(data) {
  hasPin.value = data;
}

function setAccessToken(value) {
  let userInfo = { ...loggedUser?.value, access_token: value };
  setLoggedUser(userInfo);
}
function setRefreshToken(value) {
  let userInfo = { ...loggedUser?.value, refresh_token: value };
  setLoggedUser(userInfo);
}
function updateUser(value) {
  let userInfo = { ...loggedUser?.value, fullName: value };
  setLoggedUser(userInfo);
}
function updateAccountType(value) {
  let userInfo = { ...loggedUser?.value, accountType: value };

  setLoggedUser(userInfo);
}
function updateUserInfo(data) {
  let userInfo = { ...loggedUser?.value, ...data };
  setLoggedUser(userInfo);
}

const logOut = () => {
  const authCookie = useCookie('auth')
  localStorage.clear();
  authCookie.value = null
  window.location.href = "/auth/login";
};
return {
  updateUser,
  isLoggedIn,
  refresh_token,
  access_token,
  roles,
  userId,
  userInfo,
  setRefreshToken,
  setAccessToken,
  updateAccountType,
  updateUserInfo,
  setLoggedUser,
  logOut,
  loggedUser,
  businessId,
  language,
  setHasPin,
  hasPin,
};
 },
{
  persist: {
  storage: persistedState.cookies,
   },
  }
);

I added the code to my auth store setup, at the bottom you can see where i specified cookie as the storage option

What is the issue? It's unknown how you use pinia and cookies together, and what this has to do with nuxt. Generally you can prepend cookie domain with . to make it work with subdomains

Maybe i didnt explain well, i use pinia for state management and  Pinia-plugin-persistedstate to persist the state with cookies as the storage option, so the issue is setting a domain while persisting the state to the cookie store. I dont think i saw anything for this on the docs

Please, update the question with how exactly you use the plugin. I assume it should be something like persist: { storage: cookies({ domain: '.mydomain.com' }) }, the option is passed to nuxt,  https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-cookie#domain

I just updated my question, you can see how i use the plugin in my auth store

Considering that cookies is a wrapper for Nuxt useCookies in the latest version of pinia-plugin-persistedstate, domain option needs to be passed with . prefix in order to apply a cookie to a domain and its subdomains:
{
  persist: {
    storage: persistedState.cookies({ domain: '.mydomain.com' })
  },
}

In earlier plugin versions cookiesWithOptions is used instead of cookies for the same purpose.

I tried this, but got an error,
Uncaught TypeError: persistedState.cookies is not a function

It is in the current version. It looks like it was called cookiesWithOptions in the previous one https://github.com/prazdevs/pinia-plugin-persistedstate/blob/v3/docs/frameworks/nuxt-3.md#cookieswithoptions

Yeah you are right, i tried with cookiesWithOptions, and it works fine , maybe you can update your answer to also include the version that works with cookiesWithOptions, thanks alot

Glad it helped.
